# Portfolio items rearranging

Tags: jquery, css

I want to move the portfolio items with the active category on the first row.
At this moment the inactive categories just hide.

```
var Portfolio = {
sort: function(items) {
    items.show();
    $('#portfolio-content').find('div.portfolio-item').not(items).slideUp(500);
},
showAll: function(items) {
    items.fadeIn(500);
},
doSort: function() {
    $('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function() {

        var $a = $(this);
        if (!$a.is('#all')) {

            var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#portfolio-content');

            Portfolio.sort(items);

        } else {

            Portfolio.showAll($('div.portfolio-item', '#portfolio-content'));


        }

    });
}
};

Portfolio.doSort();​
```

I want them to move after the items with the active category.
You can see an example here  http://codecanyon.net/item/the-wall-media-gallery-jquery-powered/full_screen_preview/223915